# How do I Deal with Facebook Rate Limits?

Tags: facebook, web-services, facebook-graph-api, caching, facebook-like

I'm developing an application that tallies Facebook likes of pages.  I'm currently calling Facebook's Graph API for the like counts but I found that if I call it more than 600 times in 600 seconds that I'm suspended for the next 15 minutes.

My question is, how do I deal with this?  I have the query results caching each page count for a minute but if I have way more than 600 pages and I want to display all 600+ likes for the pages I can still go over the rate limit.  How do I get around this?

I'm thinking of creating a Windows service that queries Facebook every x seconds for each like and storing the most up-to-date values in my own database.  Then I use my database to query the latest value.  But I feel there must be an easier or better way to handle this?

I looked into real-time updates (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1) but I'm afraid our server won't be able to handle the calls coming from Facebook and my understanding is I still need to call Facebook to get the actual like/share count.

```
public async Task<List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>> GetTopTen()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> pageVotes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    List<string> pageIds = await GetAllPageIds();
    foreach(string pid in pageIds)
    {
        pageVotes[pid] = await GetLikes(pid);
    }

    return pageVotes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(10).ToList();
}

private async Task<int> GetLikes(string pageId)
{
    string thisCacheKey = "GetProfileVotes_" + GetUniqueCacheKey(pageId);
    ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    int? result = cache[thisCacheKey] as int?;

    if (result == null)
    {
        string websiteURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteURL"];
        string url = Path.Combine(websiteURL, "Page", pageId);

        try
        {
            string jsonString = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://graph.facebook.com/" + url);

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Dictionary<string, object> results = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.Deserialize<object>(jsonString);

            object idValue = "";
            object likeValue = "";
            bool success = results.TryGetValue("id", out idValue);
            bool likes = results.TryGetValue("shares", out likeValue);

            if (success)
            {
                if (likes)
                    result = (int)likeValue;
                else
                    result = 0; // Facebook returns null "shares" for 0 votes

                // Save the last successful pull
                SaveLastFacebookLikeCount(pageId, result.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                result = -1;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            result = -1;
        }

        if(result < 0)
        {
            result = GetLastFacebookLikeCount(pageId);
        }

        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60);
        cache.Set(thisCacheKey, result, policy);
    }

    return result.Value;
}
```

Comment: Looks like I just got downvoted.  :(Please let me know if I missed something or didn't provide enough info, etc.  Thank you!

Comment: you only cache for a minute? the only way to deal with this is to improve your caching and not call the api that often.

Comment: I wanted results to be as up to date as possible. The Windows service solution should work but I feel there must be another way. Even if I cache every 5 minutes there's chances of hitting the rate limit. I.e. cache for 600 of the 2500 items expire at the same time and then 600 request are made. I have one page that lists all the page counts so this can happen easily.

Comment: cache every 1 hour should be more than enough for page likes. rate limits are there for a good reason, the more processing power you take for your app, the less there is available for other devs ;)

Comment: I'm convinced the cache timing will not work. I'm ranking/tallying page likes so if I query all to figure out which ones are say the top 10 the query will check if the cache expired for all records.  If 600 expire at the same time then all 600 will get refreshed.  I'll add some code to show what I got.

Comment: Added some code.  And thank you luschn for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Rate limits details & numbers were documented publicly last month:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, it may give you guidance & exact numbers on how to build around these.